# In beginner scheme how do I consume and combine two lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out a question that takes a list of first names and a list of last name and create a new list of email addresses with the first letter of the first name and up to 7 letters of the last name and @yahoo.com.

example:

```
(check-expect 
    (emails-list (list "John" "Sarah") (list "King" "Dickinson")) 
    (list "jking@yahoo.com" "sdickins@yahoo.com"))

(check-expect (emails-list empty empty) empty)
```

So far I have:

```
(define (appendnames alof alos)
  (cond [(and (empty? alof) (empty? alos)) empty]
        [else (string-append 
                (substring (first alof) 0 1) 
                (cond [(< (string-length (first alos)) 8) (first alos)]
                      [else (substring (first alos) 0 7)]) 
                "@yahoo.com")]))

(define (emails-list alof alos)
  (cond [(and (empty? alof) (empty? alos)) empty]
        [else (appendnames alof alos)]))
```

What I don't know how to do is how to make the first letters lowercase and where to put in the recursion so that appendnames will (appendnames (rest alof) (rest alos)).

Thanks so much for any help I can get!

Comment: How much can you use, of Racket's built-in procedures? for example - is it OK to use `map`? or `sequence-map`? or the answer must be in terms of basic procedures (student level)?

Comment: I am using beginner scheme with list abbreviations and have not learned map yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this looks like homework so I'll give you some hints, it'll be much better if you try to solve the problem by your own means. The first thing is - split the problem in two parts to make it simpler:

```
(define (emails-list alof alos)
  (if <???>                              ; if any of the lists is empty
      <???>                              ; return the empty list
      (cons (make-email <???> <???>)     ; create a new email with current values
            (emails-list <???> <???>)))) ; and advance the recursion
```

The interesting part of course, will be creating the actual email. Refer to the [character](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html) and [string](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-string%29%29) procedures available, here's the general idea:

```
(define (make-email name surname)
  (<???>                    ; convert the whole string to lowercase
   (<???>                   ; append the three parts of the email
    (string (<???> name 0)) ; create a new string with the frist char in name
    <???>                   ; create a substring with last name (*)
    "@yahoo.com")))         ; add the email domain
```

The step marked with `(*)` requires a bit more explanation. Notice that we're interested in *at most* seven characters from the surname, which can be easily obtained with the `substring` procedure, as long as we remember that the end index is either 7 or the string's length, if the string's length is less than seven.

Comment: What I don't understand is how to make the recursion as I have the code for making the first email but i don't know how or where to put in the recursion to make the rest of the emails.

Comment: @JamesLalonde look at the skeleton solution above: the recursion creates a new list, so we `cons` the newly created email with the recursive call over the rest of the list. It's the usual recipe for recurring and creating lists, you must have seen it in class and/or in your textbook

Comment: I have finished all the code but I am still stuck on how to convert lower case letters. So far I have 
(define (make-email name surname)
  (cond
    [(<(string-length surname) 8)(string-append (substring name 0 1) surname "@uwaterloo.ca")]
    [else (string-append(substring name 0 1)(substring surname 0 7) "@uwaterloo.ca")]))

Comment: Hint: use `string-downcase` on the whole string for converting it. And watch it, the `(substring surname 0 7)` will fail if the surname has less than 7 characters!

Comment: For the version of scheme I am using, string-downase is not defined and I would have to write it myself which I have trouble with. I have used a cond to make sure it takes in consideration words with less than 7 letters Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already read it, you should read this chapter of HtDP, which explains how to design functions that take two complex inputs:

http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-22.html

The HtDP chapter talks about three kinds of situations (or "cases") in which you need to process two complex arguments. Which situation matches the problem you're trying to solve?

How many `cond` clauses should you have? What are they? What do you have available to work with in the answer part of each clause? (In other words, what is the function's template?)

Once you get that far, it should be pretty easy to fill in the code. If you get stuck, use your concrete examples to help you.